# Can't get image into excel header using openpyxl or win32com

Tags: python, excel, header, openpyxl, win32com

I need to get an image file into an Excel header in an automated fashion; I don't believe this is possible in openpyxl, but I thought it might be doable in win32com, though I am not able to get it working.  Does anyone know a way to do this?  I found an excel macro that successfully does it within Excel:

```
Sub InsertPicture
 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture
  .FileName = "C:/Users/bharris/Desktop/my_image_file.png"
  .Height = 45
  .Width = 30
  .CropTop = -30
 End With
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&;G"
```

So I tried implementing from within python using win32com:

```
excel = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb=excel.Workbooks.Open(my_excel_file.xlsx')
ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName ="my_image_file.png"
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&;G"
wb.SaveAs('my_excel_file.xlsx')
wb.Close(True, 'my_excel_file.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

but it gives me:

```
raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.FileName' can not be set.
```

So it looks like FileName is not a property within win32com like it is in VBA within Excel.  I've tried some different combinations of things and nothing seems to work.  If anyone knows how to do this, with any type of openpyxl or win32com code, or any other code (though it has to be able to edit an existing spreadsheet, not just write a new one like xlsxwriter), your help is much appreciated!

P.S. I have found several solutions for how to insert an image into a cell, but this question is for inserting into the header specifically.

Thanks much,
Robert

Comment: I'd suggest trying xlwings to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it doesn't seem like xlwings can do this either, it can only insert an image into cells.   Unless anyone has found a way to put it in the header?  This seems like it would be a somewhat common issue so hopefully one of the python-excel packages tackle this in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.FileName ="my_image_file.png"

ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&;G"
```

use

```
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename ="my_image_file.png"

ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).